# Logstash add dynamic whitelist names based on a filed value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have a simple Json file log which I need to pass it into elasticsearch. It contains a structure similar to this.

```
{
  "component_name": "abc",
  "abc": "this is abc",
  "component_action": "action"
}
```

While passing into elasticsearch, I need to whitelist column names based on the value of the "component_name" field. In the above example, as the component name is "abc", I need to whitelist only "abc" column.
I tried to access the field value using `[fieldname]` syntax but it did not work

```
whitelist_names => [ "[component_name]" ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable interpolation

```
whitelist_names => [ "%{component_name}" ]
interpolate => true
```